# How to avoid Firebase warning that I’m using the development build?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, es6-modules

I'm making a login page for my ReactJS app using the firebase `auth` package.

I have imported the `auth` package in my global firebase file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
};

export default firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Now in my `LoginComponent` I need to access the class`FacebookAuthProvider` which is part of the `firebase.auth` namespace. 
In order to get access to this class I import the `auth` namespace.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { auth } from 'firebase';

class Login extends Component {
    provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
```

Because of this last import I’m getting the following warning in my console:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

After going through so much documentation and code I still haven’t been able to figure out how to get rid of this warning while being able to access the `FacebookAuthProvider` class.

A second question: Am I actually using the full firebase development SDK at this moment? I only imported the `auth` namespace, right??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your login component is importing the full Firebase SDK, which is what leads to that warning. You will have to import only the parts that you need. Your bundler or browser will dedupe if the same file has been loaded already.

Change this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
```

To this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Comment: In the `LoginComponent`? So I would have those imports twice, right? Once in my firebase config/initialization file and once in my `LoginComponent`? I'm a bit confused by your answer since you also got rid of the first line importing `React` and `Component` which I would need to build my component

Comment: That second bit was a copy/paste mistake. Thanks for spotting, I added it back. Your login component now seems to be reimporting the full Firebase SDK, which is what leads to that warning. You will have to import only the parts that you need. Your bundler or browser will then dedupe if the same file is loaded unnecessarily.

Comment: thanks Frank, your answer makes sense. I find it crazy that I didn't find information or an example of this anywhere. Perhaps I looked in the wrong spots. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: now my login component imports `firebase.auth` from the firebase package, and uses this method to create an authentication provider and to do the actual authenticating. 
But isn’t this a bit weird, to not use the configured firebase instance that I’ve exported in my global firebase config file `export default firebase.initializeApp(config);` ?

Comment: `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` has no default export.